# Часть ссылки как параметр

Tags: php, .htaccess

Допустим, есть ссылка: «www.example.com/catalog/value/»
И нужно, чтобы перейдя по ней пользователь увидел содержимое главной страницы ( www.example.com ), но при этом туда же было бы передано значение «value» (например, чтобы просто отобразить на экране).
Подскажите, как правильно такое осуществить?

Comment: У вас в php есть полный url. Выкусить из него нужный кусок тривиальная задача

Answer (score 1):

Пример файла .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/catalog/([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)$ catalog.php?value=$1
RewriteRule ^/catalog/([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)/$ catalog.php?value=$1
```

Тогда файл catalog.php получит get параметр `$_GET['value']`, в котором будет содержаться все, что ввел пользователь в адресной строке после /catalog/....

`A-Z` - указывает на то, что после /catalog/... можно использовать строчные латинские буквы

`a-z` - указывает на то, что после /catalog/... можно использовать прописные латинские буквы

`0-9` - указывает на то, что после /catalog/... можно использовать также цифры

`\_` - указывает на то, что после /catalog/... можно использовать знак подчеркивание

Адрес: `/catalog/Application_98` или `/catalog/Application_98/` запустит на исполнение файл `catalog.php` и в скрипте будет доступен `$_GET['value'] = "Application_98"`

Вместо `catalog.php` используйте свой скрипт. Если за отрисовку главной страницы у Вас отвечает скрипт `index.php`, замените в выше представленном примере `catalog.php` на `index.php`

Если необходимо также распознавать раздел сайта, который запросил пользователь (в вашем случае разделом сайта является `catalog`), то `.htaccess` должен быть такой:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)$ index.php?section=$1
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)/$ index.php?section=$1
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)$ index.php?section=$1&value=$2
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)/$ index.php?section=$1&value=$2
```

Тогда при запросе `/catalog/Application_98/` в файле `index.php` у Вас будут доступны два параметра `$_GET['section'] = "catalog"` и `$_GET['value'] = "Application_98"`

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Это то, что надо. Только условие почему-то не проходят (проверял на https://htaccess.madewithlove.be )

Comment: Есть позрения, что сайт https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ не сможет проверяет иные правила htaccess. Любые примеры с переадресацией способом RewriteRule на этом сайте не отрабатываются и вываливается ошибка: "This rule was not met - Это правило не было соблюдено". Точнее, валятся все тесты с регулярными выражениями (что-то вроде ([A-Za-z0-9\_]+))